# HTML parsing not working as expected using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python 3 and the BeautifulSoup module, version 4.9.3. I'm trying to use this package to practice parsing some simple HTML.

The string I have is the following:

`text = '''<li><p>Some text</p>is put here</li><li><p>And other text is put here</p></li>'''`

I use BeautifulSoup as follows:

`x = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")`

I then experiment with Beautiful Soup's functionality with the following script:

```python
for li in x.find_all('li'):
    print(li)
    print(li.string)
    print(li.next_element)
    print(li.next_element)
    print(li.next_element.string)
    print("\n")
```

The results (at least for the first iteration) are unexpected:

```html
<li><p>Some text</p>is put here</li>
None
<p>Some text</p>
Some text


<li><p>And other text is here</p></li>
And other text is here
<p>And other text is here</p>
And other text is here
```

Why is the `string` attribute of the first `li` tag None, whereas the `string` attribute of the inner `p` tag is not None?

Similarly, if I do:

`x.find_all('li', string=re.compile('text'))`

I only get one result (the 2nd tag).

But if I do:

```python
for li in x.find_all('li'):
    print(li.find_all(string=re.compile('text')))
```

I get 2 results (both tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paraphrasing [the doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string):

> 1. If a tag has only one child, and that child is a `NavigableString`, the child is made available as `.string`.
> 2. If a tag’s only child is another tag, and that tag has a `.string`, then the parent tag is considered to have the same `.string` as its child.
> 3. If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what `.string` should refer to, so `.string` is defined to be None.

Let's apply these rules to your question:

> Why is the string attribute of the first `li` tag `None`, whereas the string attribute of the inner `p` tag is not `None`?

The inner `p` tag satisfies rule #1; it has exactly one child, and that child is a `NavigableString`, so `.string` returns that child.

The first `li` satisfies rule #3; it has more than one child, so `.string` would be ambiguous.

---

Considering your second question, let's consult [the doc for the `string=` argument to `.find_all()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument)

> With `string` you can search for strings instead of tags. ... Although `string` is for finding strings, you can combine it with arguments that find tags: Beautiful Soup will find all tags whose `.string` matches your value for string.

Your first example:

```py
x.find_all('li', string=re.compile('text'))
# [<li><p>And other text is put here</p></li>]
```

That searches for all of the `li` tags whose `.string` matches the regular expression. But we have already seen that the first `li`'s `.string` is `None`, so it doesn't match.

Your second example:

```py
for li in x.find_all('li'):
    print(li.find_all(string=re.compile('text')))
# ['Some text']
# ['And other text is put here']
```

This searches for all of the strings contained anywhere in each of the `li` trees. For the first tree, `li.p.string` exists and matches, even if `li.string` doesn't.

Comment: @akrylic - I added an answer for the second part of your question.